# SDL2, Linux - Вопрос!

Tags: linux, sdl2

При установке SDL2, используя команду `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev`, OpenGL тоже устанавливаеться?

Comment: Устанавливается вся цепочка зависимостей пакета. У вас убунта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если [посмотреть по зависимостям](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libsdl2-dev), то устанавливается mesa - реализация opengl под свободные драйвера.

`-lGL` - это папка `/usr/include/GL/` находится в пакете    `mesa-common-dev`, который установится вместе с `libsdl2-dev`

Comment: Я типо хочу узнать нужно ли мне устанавливать дополнительно драйвера OpenGL, для того чтобы скомпилировать код - `g++ file.cpp -o file -lSDL2 -lGL`

Comment: @RedBull добавил в ответ

Answer (score -1):

В пакетном менеджере Muon или Synaptic или в терминале.

Нужно установить следующие пакеты:

libghc-sdl2-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-net-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-dev

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все необходимые зависимости также будут установлены.

Общий размер установки примерно 1 гигабайт.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: представьте, что приложенная вами картинка «потерялась». без неё ведь ответ полностью лишается смысла. добавьте, пожалуйста, текстовое описание того, что вы предлагаете сделать (нажав [edit])